# UIScrollView with UIView as content do not scrolls

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, swift2

I have created following layout:

[image]

As you can see I have ScrollView which only child is View and then I have other views inside this view. However it scroll view does not scroll. I have seen many approaches how to fix this but the one I have used is supposed to be working without any additional code which is what I wanted to achieve.

Any ideas how to fix this and make scroll view working without using any additional code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have autolayout errors (the red lines and the red arrow to the right of your scene name).

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution,

set constant height for view inside the scrollView .

Reason:

From the above constraint you have set only boundary conditions for scrollView. It should have content size so fix the height constraint for that view.

Comment: I cant set fixed size because my content is dynamically loaded from XML

Comment: you can change the height constraint based on xml height.